# Extract a part of the string from comma separated string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `varchar` string in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @vStr VARCHAR(MAX) = ';ABC,DEF,+123456789,+987654321,0,0,0,0,0,+987654321,1110:'
```

For this string I want result like:

```
'+123456789,+987654321,0,0,0,0,0,+987654321'

DECLARE @vStr VARCHAR(MAX) = ';PQR,XYZ,+987654321,+987654321,0,0,0,0,0,+9876123456,5555:'
```

should generate result like:`+987654321,+987654321,0,0,0,0,0,+9876123456`

I am trying `substring` with `left` and `len` but it is not working.

**UPDATE:**

In general I do not want first two part of this comma separated string and also I do not want last part of the comma separated string.

Comment: do you have mix alpha + numeric case ? like ABC123, DEF123 ?

Comment: yes @Squirrel.. it is a possibility

Comment: What's the general rule? From the first string with `+` up to the last string with `+`?

Comment: so ABC123 is in or out of the result ?

Comment: @FelixPamittan General rule is I do not want first two values from coma separated string. For first string I do not want ";ABC" and "Def,". and I do not want last portion. i.e. 1110 in first example. I hope I have made my self clear

Comment: i didn't got what exactly you looking for. Please try this may help you
SELECT substring(@vStr,10,len(@vStr)-15)

Comment: There are data types *designed* for holding multiple values. There are two built into SQL Server - XML and tables. Why not *use* such datatypes rather than force yourself to use SQL Server's (weak) string processing functions to try to extract meaningful data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  result = stuff(item, 1, charindex(',', item, charindex(',', item) + 1), '')
from
(
    -- exclude last item
    select  item = left(@vStr, len(@vStr) - charindex(',', reverse(@vStr)))
) d
```

explaination

- the inner query is to exlude the last item. This is done by using reversing the string (reverse()) and then find the comma "," and then use LEFT() to get the left part up to the last comma
- the 2 charindex() on the outer query is to find the 2nd comma
- And then remove whatever up the 2nd comma using stuff()

Comment: Brilliant solution! Would be better if you include some more explanation.

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks for this timely solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you Please try this

```
select substring( substring (substring(@vStr,1,len(@vStr)),10,len(@vStr)),0,len(@vStr)-14 )
```

Comment: Your answer works for the both examples I have given above. But I have plenty of strings which I need to parse. See the general expected result I have updated in question. Your this solution does not work with Select @vStr = ';1GALQR,20111,19727328849,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,583424:'